# break a string into usable arguments

Tags: node.js, string, parsing, arguments

I have a string that I'm inputting into a node client which gets passed to a server.
let's say it's this on the client side:

```
    "foo 5" or 
    "bar foo".
```

one of those is a function, and one of those is a argument for that function in my server. I need to parse those strings into my code such that I can manipulate them in the manner needed, such as: (server side)

```
    socket.write(moduleName.foo('5'));
    //expected result: someValueOfFoo.
```

or

```
    socket.write(moduleName.bar('foo'));
    //expected result: someValueOfBar.
```

I don't know how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can assume that the first word is the function name and the second word is the parameter separated by a space, then you could do something like this:

```
const args = string.split(" ")
const func = args[0]
const vars = args[1]

socket.write(moduleName[func](vars))
```

This works because you can access functions as a property of an object, and then call them normally, for example:

```js
// Test module object with function foo
const myModule = {
  foo: function(n) {
    console.log('foo was called with value:', n)
  }
}

// Test case 
const string = 'foo 5'
const args = string.split(" ")
const func = args[0]
const vars = args[1]

// Call func on myModule with vars
myModule[func](vars)
```

Comment: @AndrewSteier glad to help!